# How can I open a jQuery UI modal dialog in ASP.Net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have been going crazy trying to open a modal dialog box in ASP.Net (C#)! I have followed two walkthroughs, but I am not getting any results. All I get is the complete web page with no dialog box, but now a "X" is in the upper right corner. Can anyone please tell me how to do a simple dialog box?

Here's my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog();
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">
    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">I'm in a dialog.. Really!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong with your code. Are the jquery script files and css files correct and linked in properly? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/67kME/) is demo that shows your code working.

**Edit**: Actually I just noticed something. Just like undefined mentioned your link to your css seems to be incorrect. You have the link type as being `text/javascript` when it should be `text/css`.

The link for your css file should most likely look like this:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Comment: Actually that was the problem! I had type="text/javascript" instead of type="text/css"!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a strict doctype, try changing link tag to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery-ui.css" />`, it sounds that the stylesheet is not loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help! I got it to work! However the "X" doesn't appear on the upper right corner. Is there a simple fix for that?

Comment: @stevekershaw i had neglected the type attribute, yes you should position the container relatively. when using `position: absolute` the element is positioned relative to it's nearest relatively positioned parent element.